# Remote kafka producer best practices

Tags: apache-kafka

Considering the following setup:

- Kafka Cluster in single data center
- Remote server locations around the world

The remote server locations are trusted, meaning they could produce to kafka.

**What is the best practice for handling long roundtrips / unstable connections with kafka?** E.g. in this case when the producers are far away from the cluster.

I see 2 solutions to handle this:

- Directly connect a kafka producer from the remote servers
- Use a gateway (e.g. http REST) that accepts incoming messages and produces them to kafka

**Considerations:**

- Security / Authentication / Encryption

  - out of the box with https
- Reliability

  - http server (cluster) as bottleneck?
- Throughput

  - http headers / message batching increase avg message payload size?

I see pros/cons for both approaches but I'm wondering if somebody here had the same problem in the past.

Comment: If you your clients can tolerate latency, I would suggest a REST wrapper and may be a long living(KEEP ALIVE) HTTP sessions if you need high through put. If you are in a cloud env, never recommend the consumers to directly publish the message because as you know its not only the payload, a ton of metrics, heath check and behind the house keeping Kafka activities will add up the traffic. But if your application is mission critical, you can consider a direct connect but think of situation where you need to patch the Kafka version or a critical CVE, you need to patch all producers, better REST

Comment: @Valath Thanks for the reply! Your recommendations make sense to me. I also don't like that the remote servers will use the kafka api directly, meaning that if there are changes in the kafka cluster we might have to redeploy them. The http REST server cluster just seems to be the lesser evil here as long as the event schema is stable.

Comment: May be this can help https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#assembly-kafka-bridge-quickstart-bridge, you dont need to start from scratch

Comment: Alternatively, create "edge" clusters in all local DC and create a hub and spoke architecture where the central cluster will pull in the remote data, which will have better delivery guarantees than being pushed, due to nature of how Kafka offsets get committed. This also isolates downtime unless the central cluster goes down

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the recommendation! Hub and spoke sounds like a good fit for my use case, I'll look into it.